# Java JAR unable to load class on Class-Path?

Tags: java, jar

I have a jar file that uses a class within a second jar file. However, when I run the first jar file, I get an exception that the class can not be found. I can't find any documentation on how to troubleshoot the issue.

I have two .jar files, MyApp.jar and sqljdbc42.jar. Both of these .jar files are in the same directory.

MyApp.jar has the following code in the main:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

The manifest for MyApp.jar has the following:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.mycompany.myapp.MyApp
Class-Path: sqljdbc42.jar
<blank line>
```

The class `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` is in the jar sqljdbc42.jar.

When MyApp.jar is executed, the following exception occurs:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
```

Using Java 8, built in IntelliJ, verified the manifest contents by opening the jar in 7Zip.
Any advice on how I can get this (seemingly simple, basic piece of Java JAR concept) working would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it work when you run `java -classpath "MyApp.jar;sqljdbc42.jar" com.mycompany.myapp.MyApp` ? I know this is not what you want, but it might help to locate the cause.

Comment: @KeesKist Wow, that does work! What I was trying before was `java -classpath "slqjdbc42.jar" -jar MyApp.jar` which did not work. I am not sure of the difference between the two? For the moment I am sending the project to test with a bat file, but I would love to know how to fix the issue based on this? I have other things that need to be built that will use the same sqljdbc42.jar file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three ways to solve your issue:

1) You can generate your jar using IDE "[Eclipse Neon](http://www.eclipse.org/neon/)".

- create folder in your project "lib" and put `sqljdbc42.jar` into it;
- add `sqljdbc42.jar` to the classPath: Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add JARs... (select your jar from "lib");
- Right click on your project -> Export... -> Runnable JAR file -> Launch configuration (choose you main class) and check Library handing: **Extract required libraries into generated JAR**.

Eclipse will **repack all reference libraries automatically** without any security issues and `ClassNotFound` exceptions.

2) We should convert project into Maven project. And then use special plugins for generating JARs and creating dependencies of custom libs.

3) We can even generate it using Intellij Idea. But we should create Artifact of application with configuration where all signed libraries will be outside of your generated jar.

I think that the first variant is the easiest. Check it. If it does not help I will describe other methods with more details.